# Is there a component framework like Vue or React except server side?

Tags: components, web-frameworks

Is there a component framework like Vue or React except server side, that will let you define your html, css, and js in one component file and then compile them down in a single compilation phase?

Comment: You can do that in almost any language. For example write a PHP file with all html, js and css inline. Why would you though?

Comment: What I'm kind of talking about is a component version though.  Where you can define components with all of those elements and then a compiler will compile those into their individual files.  Basically the idea that Vue and React use to create components except on the server side.

Comment: I don't understand actually. Usually server side is headless. Which means you have usually only an api and that's all. The fancy stuff like html, js is only used on frontend side.

Comment: Right agreed and sorry for the confusion. But what I mean is like a Babel transpiler or Sass transpiler, except instead of transpilng just one language, it can take a component  built from html/css/js and transpile those into their individual files, which is then served from back end.